# How can I make login redirects from a URL on my Wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

My redirect function in functions.php has this structure--

```
//After Login Redirection
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    $user_id = (isset($user->ID) ? $user->ID : false);
    $urlparameters = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $decode = urldecode($urlparamiters);
    preg_match('~=(.*?)&~',$decode, $redirecturl);
    
    //If the paramiter redirect_to is found in the url then run the url redirect.
    if(strpos($urlparameters, "redirect_to")!== false) {
        return $redirecturl[1];
    } else {
        //If no redirect in the URL then use standard redirect according to roles
        if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {
            if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
                //is this the administrator?
                $redirect_to = home_url( $path = '/wordpress/wp-admin/', $scheme = 'https' );
            }
            elseif (in_array('client', $user->roles)) {
                // Take clients to the private messaging board
                $redirect_to = home_url( $path = '/wordpress/pm/', $scheme = 'https' ); 
            }
        }
        return $redirect_to;
    } 
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

**WHAT I WANT AND WHAT I GET**

When customers access my site it is either directly from the wp-login.php page or because they have been sent to a specific page.  If sent to a specific page the url will contain a log in redirect parameter. If the url has a parameter starting with "redirect_to" I only want to run that redirect.  If there is not parameter in the URL I want to run my standard redirect sequence. The above code does not work. It is only running my standard redirection routine. So, my first IF condition is not working and I am not sure why.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED AND WHAT I SEE**

When I land on the login page, If I echo back `$urlparameters` I can see they are being caught accurately.  If I echo back $decode and `$redirecturl[1]` I see the values I expect. However I hit the login button, the function runs as if the `$urlparameters`, `$decode`, and `$redirecturl[1]` variables are empty.

If I use a redirect URL, and I remove the second IF condition (disable the ability to use the standard redirect) customers are directed to their WordPress profile screen. So it is as if `$redirecturl[1]` is just empty.  If I make `$redirecturl[1]` the only option for redirect the same happens (no conditions).  If I keep the second IF condition in place, the code runs as if no parameters are in the URL and the standard redirects are completed.

The error log produces Undefined offset: 1 for `$redirecturl[1]` indicating that it is empty.  And yet I see a value when I echo the variable.

**Please help me understand the following:**

Why are my variables (`$urlparameters`, `$decode`, and `$redirecturl[1]`) echoing back the expected values but are functioning as if they are empty when I hit the login button.  How can I correct this?

Am I losing the session data because I have hit the login button? If so, how can I maintain the data into the next screen?

Answer (score 1):

Updated Code:

```
//After Login Redirection
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    $user_id = (isset($user->ID) ? $user->ID : false);
    $urlparameters = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $decode = urldecode($urlparamiters);
    preg_match('~=(.*?)&~',$decode, $redirecturl);
    setcookie("urlparamiters", $urlparamiters, time()+120);
    setcookie("redirecturl", $redirecturl[1], time()+120);

    //If the paramiter redirect_to is found in the url then run the url redirect.
    if(strpos($_COOKIE["urlparamiters"], "redirect_to") !== false){
        return $_COOKIE["redirecturl"];
    } else {
        //If no redirect in the URL then use standard redirect according to roles
        if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {
            if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
                //is this the administrator?
                $redirect_to = home_url( $path = '/wordpress/wp-admin/', $scheme = 'https' );
            }
            elseif (in_array('client', $user->roles)) {
                // Take clients to the private messaging board
                $redirect_to = home_url( $path = '/wordpress/pm/', $scheme = 'https' ); 
            }
        }
        return $redirect_to;
    } 
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

What I found is that I was losing data when pushing the login button because it was  not maintaining the session.  So, my solution was to use cookies to manage this.  It works as intended now.